# Save Attachments and Email separately

Tags: vba, outlook

The user will select an email.
I need to save all its attachments to a folder + a copy of that email, without attachments, in a separate folder.

**Attachments are removed from the original email in my Inbox. After removing attachments I am calling SaveAs method so I think this should not happen.**

```vb
Dim objMailItemOriginal As Outlook.MailItem
Dim objMailItemNew As Outlook.MailItem
Dim objNameSpaceUserNS As Outlook.namespace
Dim emailPath$, tmpFolder$

Set objMailItemOriginal = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)
Set objMailItemNew = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set objNameSpaceUserNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

tmpFolder = Environ("Temp") & "\" & Format$(Now, "hh_mm_ss")
MkDir tmpFolder

emailPath = Environ$("Temp") & "\tmpEmail.msg"

Dim attachPath$
For i = objMailItemOriginal.Attachments.Count To 1 Step -1
    attachPath = tmpFolder & "\" & objMailItemOriginal.Attachments(i)
    objMailItemOriginal.Attachments(i).SaveAsFile attachPath
    
    objMailItemNew.Attachments.Add attachPath
    objMailItemOriginal.Attachments.Remove (i)
Next

objMailItemOriginal.SaveAs emailPath
objMailItemOriginal.Close olDiscard
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

only way I can think of would be to save the E-Mail including attachments, then open the saved E-Mail from the disk and work with the attachments in there.

```
Sub workwithmail(pathfile As string)
Dim oNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
 Set oNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Dim oSharedItem As Outlook.mailitem
Dim pathfile As String
    Set oSharedItem = oNamespace.OpenSharedItem(pathfile)

  '''here Comes your code

    oSharedItem.Close (olSave)
    Set oSharedItem = Nothing
    Set oNamespace = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: It works, BUT the size of the file without attachments is the same as with. I have to use saveAs again with another filename to lower the filesize. How is it possible to "overwrite" the file to lower the size?

Comment: Found one. I will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Do not delete the attachments from the original item. Save the message as an MSG file using MailItem.SaveAs, reopen it using Application.Session.OpenSharedItem (returns MailItem object) and remove attachments from that object. Then call MailItem.Save.

Answer (score 0):

To lower the size of the file without the attachments you could do this:

```
oSharedItem.SaveAs "filePath here"
oSharedItem.Close olDiscard
```

Then the attachments are still in the original mail in the outlook explorer and the saved file is smaller.